# Linked Stylesheet in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, stylesheet

I am trying to build a second .css file for my company's website.
Currently, we are using a responsive theme, so most of our content displays correctly on desktop and mobile browsers. However, recently the boss is requesting custom code that is unresponsive. In order to keep the site looking good, I want to apply a secondary stylesheet that contains formatting for mobile devices. It would be like this for any html page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domain.tld/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

I cannot figure out how to get this into a wordpress child theme correctly. Can anyone offer suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the header.php file in your child theme directory, or under "Appearance"->"Editor" in the main menu of the your Wordpress adminpanel. You can paste the link to your new stylesheet there.

Also consider moving the styles to your theme's directory and replacing the domain in your href with `<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>` ([example from wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was just looking under my child theme directory (I have an SCP conenction) and I noticed I do no have a header.php file in there. However, I do have a header.php file in my parent theme. Would making changes there appropriately reflect my CSS stylesheet?

Comment: It depends on your theme. If your child theme is not overriding the parent theme header, then making changes to the parent would work. I would, however, suggest that you copy the header from the parent into the child theme directory and then make the changes there. It is always best to leave the parent themes as they are... in case of future updates. For more information on how child themes work see the Wordpress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: I tried you suggestion and am still having no success. The mobile browser displays the same as the desktop version.

Comment: Either the child theme override is not functioning or your device does not read handheld styles... there is no way for me to tell what the problem is. Do you see the new stylesheet call when you inspect the source in the mobile browser? If yes, you could try changing media back to "screen" and restricting it to a specific width. For example: media='screen and (max-width: 600px)'

Comment: Not really sure if I want to debug on a mobile device. I actually found that I could modify my current style.css theme with the
        @media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 640px)  {}
I just put my CSS code between the brackets and it is working like a charm. Thanks for your suggestions though, I do understand where you are going with that train of thought.